# What are the tools to help import my data into Salesforce

Tags: import, migration

I am switching from old CRM and looking for easy to use tools to import my data

Comment: What version of Salesforce do you have? The API access that many tools require is only available for Enterprise or Unlimited editions.

Comment: question is generic...would be good to have options for different editions

Comment: I think this is a great example of a ["community wiki"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) style question, for which there isn't a clear answer.

Comment: Many tools can use the API in editions that don't support customer use of the API.  The Salesforce Data Loader is one example, but there are many others on the AppExchange.

Comment: Where have you run across support for the Apex Data Loader without access to the API? In my experience the Apex Data Loader only work on Enterprise and higher. Of course I've hear rumors that a Salesforce rep can be talked into turning API on for a limited time or can be added a la carte, but they'd much rather talk their customers in to upgrading.

Comment: Yes, I would like to see this as a community wiki post also.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have 2 options provided by Salesforce:

1: **Salesforce Import Wizard**: The easiest option built into your Salesforce.com application. To open it go to Your Name | Setup | Data Management. It works with any Salesforce edition and in many cases is enough to get your data imported.

2: **Force.com Data Loader**: Data Loader is another tool provided by Salesforce. It is a standalone application for Mac or PC and is available for download at Force.com. I would call it an advanced version of Import Wizard that allows you to do more sophisticated migration tricks. You need to be at least on Enterprise Edition to use the Data Loader.

Also various 3rd party vendors have built data import tools.

If you want to learn more, I have written a blog post about tool options for import: 
https://medium.com/import2/4-tools-to-import-data-into-salesforce-9b081b6bd101

Answer (score 19):

On the third party front, there are various free and paid solutions:

- JitterBit - http://www.jitterbit.com/salesforce/index.php. Powerful data loader with scheduling ability. Definitely worth reviewing. Simple functionality is free. More advanced features require a license
- Informatica - Popular, but expensive and not particularly functional
- Excel Connector - Class tool for power admins to import data
- Import2 - http://www.import2.com/salesforce. Easy online data import service for Salesforce
- Data2CRM - https://www.data2crm.com/migration/crm/salesforce — online service with reasonable price

Comment: JitterBit is a very neat tool. And I've only used the free version.

Comment: Yes, another vote for Jitterbit. I like that you can do basic SQL queries with it.

Answer (score 10):

You also might check out talend:

http://www.talend.com/index.php

Open Source data migration tool

Comment: Use Talend open studio all the time! and its all built in eclipse and free :)

Comment: I tried using Talend at it seemed incredibly cumbersome. Do you have any FAQs or Wikis that helped? It seems like a powerful tool...

Comment: I thought Taled is data integration tool.

Answer (score 2):

The Jitterbit Dataloader for Salesforce is awesome and FREE!  http://www.jitterbit.com/salesforce/data-loader  Hands down the best solution for almost any job.

Answer (score 2):

We are currently recommending Skyvva www.skyvva.com as this enables lookups and transformations within the integration.

It is FREE (unless you want to schedule loads and use connectors to other databases, SAP, ODBC etc) and works with Professional edition up.

If you want to upgrade to a scheduled solution you can purchase a licence for the java agent to 'push' the data on a schedule.

NB Skyvva and Skyvia are different products, we recommend Skyvva

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers there are free methods provided by Salesforce.com - the web-based import wizard and the [Data Loader](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Loader).  There are also a large number of free and paid apps available via the [AppExchange](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?type=Apps&sort=6&filter=a0L30000001Qp7TEAS) under the Integration and Data Management category.  Many of the tools have added functionality such as importing directly from databases, data cleansing, etc.. Many of those tools will also offer free trials to allow you to test in-house for a short period.

Answer (score 0):

### Salesforce CLI `data` Commands

The [Salesforce CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) has [`data`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm) commands which allow you to manipulate records in your org.

#### `data:bulk:upsert`

The [`data:bulk:upsert`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm#cli_reference_bulk_upsert) command allows you to insert new rows and update existing rows from a CSV file.

Suppose you have a CSV file (example.csv), formatted in the following manner, containing data to be [upserted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm) into the [`Contact`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Contact.htm) sObject:

```
* ------------------------------------------------------ *
| Id                 | FirstName | LastName | Phone      |
| ------------------------------------------------------ |
|                    | John      | Doe      | 5558675309 |
| ------------------------------------------------------ |
| 003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | Jane      | Doe      | 5552738255 |
* ------------------------------------------------------ *
```

The source of the CSV file would look something like this:

```
Id,FirstName,LastName,Phone
,John,Doe,5558675309
003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,Jane,Doe,5552738255
```

You could use the following command to insert the new contacts and update the existing contacts:

```
sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert --sobjecttype Contact --csvfile example.csv --externalid Id
```